# WMIC redirect: Invalid file name error

Tags: batch-file, filenames, wmic

I'm trying to get the list of programs off of a computer and upload that list of programs to a text file on a shared server. The code and output is below. When I run the line of code: `wmic /output:C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\temp.txt  product get name,version
pause`, I get an `Invalid file name.` error. If anyone could instruct me as to how to get rid of this error, I'd really appreciate it.

Code:

```
echo. >> "N:\Individual Files\Jerry\Projects\TroubleshootingPCIssues\audits\Audit of Software Programs on Each Computer.txt"
echo. >> "N:\Individual Files\Jerry\Projects\TroubleshootingPCIssues\audits\Audit of Software Programs on Each Computer.txt"
echo %computername% >> "N:\Individual Files\Jerry\Projects\TroubleshootingPCIssues\audits\Audit of Software Programs on Each Computer.txt"
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- >> "N:\Individual Files\Jerry\Projects\TroubleshootingPCIssues\audits\Audit of Software Programs on Each Computer.txt"
wmic /output:C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\temp.txt  product get name,version
pause
type "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\temp.txt">>"N:\Individual Files\Jerry\Projects\TroubleshootingPCIssues\audits\Audit of Software Programs on Each Computer.txt"
pause
```

Output: (2 blank lines, the comuter name, and a dashed line)(No list of program names yet)

```
`


ANTHEMDESKTOP23 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- '
```

Comment: Does `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop` exist? It might not - user profiles aren't always in `C:\Users`, and the folder name isn't always `%username%` (the domain can be appended, as can a serial number). Try `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`.

Comment: In my case, it does exist. I just forgot to put quotes around `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\temp.txt` in line 5 of my code. Thanks for your concern and input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?  `%username%` can contain spaces and that needs to be catered for.

```
wmic /output:"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\temp.txt"  product get name,version
```

As Andrew comments, this is more reliable than the above:

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\Desktop\temp.txt"  product get name,version
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to put quotes around `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\temp.txt`. When I put commas around that line of code. My script works. Using the more reliable method you described works too.